# Spillover effect in short time-series

Tags: time-series, panel-data, vector-autoregression

My goal is to identify a potential spillover effect.

I study the industry-level profitability (e.g. profitability in agriculture, profitability in finance and insurance etc.).

I calculate the industry-level profitability change based on the profitabilities of the companies within the industry. I have a panel data of approximately 6.000 companies (grouped into 19 industries) in the period of 2003 - 2020. Data is yearly (I do not have quarterly or monthly data).

Here is how it looks like. The actual table is 17 x 19 (17 years and 19 sectors). The percentage values represent the industry-level year-to-year changes in profitability.

| Sectors | 2003 | ... | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sector A | 5% | ... | 5% | 5% | 5% |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Sector Q | 5% | ... | -2% | 3% | 5% |
| Sector R | 5% | ... | 5% | -2% | 3% |
| Sector S | 5% | ... | 5% | -2% | 3% |

Please take a look at sectors Q, R and S in the period of 2018 - 2020. I exemplified what I mean by a spillover effect. You can see that once sector Q reaches a particular result (e.g. -2% in 2018), the sectors R and S follow (e.g. -2% in 2019). So the decrease/increase in profitability spills from sector Q to sectors R and S.

I thought of using VAR (Vector autoregression) as it seems perfectly suitable for studying the spillover effects. However, I came across several discussions discouraging the use of VAR when only a few time stamps (in my case, 17 years) are available. I assume it concerns PVAR (panel VAR) also. Could you please comment on the usability of VAR/PVAR in this setting or advise other methods to employ?

Comment: I haven't heard VAR not being suitable for the reason you mentioned! Can you give a reference to such a discussion? I think VAR should work well for your problem.

Comment: Dear @Amin Shn, please find the discussion I mentioned, here: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is-there-any-reference-that-supports-using-a-small-sample-in-a-VAR-model

Comment: Thanks, just had a look and the issue they are pointing to is the general N >> p rule (that the number of observations should be much greater than the number of parameters). But I think you can use Bayesian VAR models that allow you to use prior information for regularization and get reasonable results with uncertainty estimated using probability distributions using the Bayes rule.

Comment: You can also use regularization using L1, L2 or both norms, in case you want to use a frequentist model instead of a Bayesian one.